# Adding 2 Numbers in 2 TextBox

Tags: vba, addition

I'm having trouble adding 2 Integers in TextBox.  If I add 1 + 1 I get 11.

Please help..

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer

a = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
b = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
c = CInt(TextBox3.Text)

TextBox3.Value = TextBox1.Value + TextBox2.Value

c = a + b

End Sub
```

I used this code and it works too:

```
 x = CDbl(txtSurveyYes.Value) + CDbl(txtSurveyNo.Value)

        txtTotal.Value = x
```

Comment: `cint` try instead of val, you are concatenating

Comment: something like this? a = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
b = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
c = CInt(TextBox3.Text)

Comment: Thank you Nathan..It works now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the value to cint, as Nathan_Sav said, you are currently concatenating strings.

You would need to do something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

TextBox3.Value = CInt(TextBox1.Value) + CInt(TextBox2.Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Hexie, thank you so much..It works as what Nathan said I added also the one I used in my header post..please see..